# how can i have empty field with Num_Format function

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys i have used the num_format for one of my decimal fields (decimal 15,2),whenever i

am entering the value so its ok but when i wanted to have the column empty still it gives the

result of 0.00 which i dont want i have used null and removed the num_format function it

works but i want also the num_format for my field.

```
here is the code:

<?php echo $row['CurrencyType'].' '. number_format($row['price'], 2, '.', ',').' '.$row['Square Meter'] ? >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used this line of code :

```
$price   = (isset($row['price']) && $row['price']!='')?number_format($row['price'], 2, '.', ','):'null';
echo $row['CurrencyType'].' '.$price.' '.$row['Square Meter'];
```

Comment: sorry confuesed how to used it in this line----------------->   <?php echo $row['CurrencyType'].' '. number_format($row['PropostedPrice'], 2, '.', ',').' '.$row['PricePerArea']?>

Comment: it's simple i check $row['price'] value with ternary operator if it is emty then it return null otherwise price

Comment: i mean its displaying the null in page

Comment: yes if you have no need to display null then remove null from that first line